# Permuting natural numbers

Tags: algorithms, permutations, mathematical-programming

We have two integers $z, k$

We form a sequence now of first z natural numbers. i.e. $1, 2, 3, 4, \ldots z$.

Now we have to find total number of permutations of this sequence such that the sum of any two adjacent numbers is $ \le k$

( $z \leq 10^6$, $\;\;z < k < 2*z$ )

Here is what I have been able to think untill now. If `k=2*z-1,` the answer is `z!`

Now if we reduce the value of `k to 2*z-2`, then we take the highest pair as a group and permute with rest of the elements, we subtract this value from the previous case of `k=2*z-1`

i.e. `dp(z,k)= z!` for `k=2*z-1`. and `dp(z,k-1)=dp(z,k)-(z-1)!*2` for `k=2*z-2`.

I want to know if I am going in the right direction. Any help on the closed form would be good.

Comment: What is your motivation? What have you tried?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have added the limits for z,k
there must be some closed form for the above conditions, since brute forcing them seems unfeasable. I am guessing at a dp solution. I tried writing down the values for small values of z,k and trying to guess a pattern, but no good till now.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus I have added my approach.

Comment: Here is the user's motivation: http://www.codechef.com/JUNE13/problems/PERMUTE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D(z,k,l)$ be the number of permutations $p_1,\ldots,p_z$ of $1,\ldots,z$ in which the condition $p_i + p_{i+1} \leq k$ is violated exactly $l$ times. Then $D(z,k,l)$ is given by the following recurrence relation, which is valid whenever $z \geq 2$ and $z+1 \leq k \leq 2z-1$:
$$
D(z,k,l) = \begin{cases}
(z-l) D(z-1,z,z-2-l) + (l+1) D(z-1,z,z-3-l), & k = z+1, \\
(z-l) D(z-1,k-2,l) + (l+1) D(z-1,k-2,l+1), & k \neq z+1.
\end{cases}
$$
I leave the proof of correctness to you.

<sup>(Here is a hint for the first case: show that $D(z,z+1,l) = D(z,z,z-1-l)$ and that $D(z,z,l) = (z-l) D(z-1, z, l-2) + (l+1) D(z-1, z, l-1)$.)</sup>

The following Python program implements this recurrence:

```
def D(z, k, l):
    if z < 2 or k < z+1 or k >= 2*z:
        raise "Error"
    if z == 2:
        return 2 * int(l == 0)
    if k == z+1:
        return (z-l) * D(z-1, z, z-2-l) + (l+1) * D(z-1, z, z-3-l)
    return (z-l) * D(z-1, k-2, l) + (l+1) * D(z-1, k-2, l+1)
```

A more efficient implementation will use dynamic programming, I leave that also to you. One thing to notice is that case II preserves the quantity $2z-k$ while case I always has $k = z+1$, so the algorithm is quadratic rather than cubic.

For concreteness, here is a Python implementation of the dynamic programming method:

```
def DP(z, k):
    if not (z >= 2 and z+1 <= k <= 2*z-1):
        raise "Error"
    z_crit = 2*z-k+1
    L = [2, 0]
    for w in range(3, z_crit+1):
        L = [(w-l) * L[w-2-l] + (l+1) * L[w-3-l] for l in range(w-2)] + [2 * L[0], 0]
    for w in range(z_crit+1, z+1):
        L = [(w-l) * L[l] + (l+1) * L[l+1] for l in range(w-2)] + [2 * L[w-2], 0]
    return L[0]
```

Comment: Any hints for the dynamic programming structure? This recurrance looks more complex than i imagined it to be. If I calculate this value modulus a prime number. Would that help?

Comment: If you calculate the actual values for $z \approx 10^6$ then the numbers would be gigantic, so this is only really possible if you compute it modulo something.

Comment: yes and how to proceed with dynamic programming? Can this be done using matrices for multiplication? Like a transformation matrix `T^x * initial state`?

Comment: As for implementation using DP, I added a few comments. If you're lazy you can always use memoization, which is dynamic programming without planning ahead. (Memoization: store all values of $D(z,k,l)$ you compute in a table, and don't recompute a value which is already in the table.)

Comment: but even storing that table would require lots of space since z and k both reach 10^6 and there's an extra factor l involved.

Comment: The DP implementation calculates $D(z,k,\cdot)$ from $D(z-1,k-2,\cdot)$ (if $k > z+1$) and $D(z,z+1,\cdot)$ from $D(z-1,z,\cdot)$, so you can implement it using matrix multiplication. I'll leave you the details. You only need linear space.

Comment: can you also provide link to some paper or place where this is discussed in detail.?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9165/discussion-between-yuval-filmus-and-alice)